# Why does the linker sets a default rpath in ELF as its standard lib location when building C++ code with specific GCC 4.8.0 version?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I'm building my main.cpp with an linker option -Wl,-rpath, to set an additional rpath for the executable to lookup the symbols while loading.
The problem is gcc 4.8.0 linker already places a default rpath in ELF to its lib location, during the linking phase. The default rpath placed by linker is overriding the  given at command line to the linker.
How do I suppress/override this default rpath added by linker.
Note: I don't see this issue with GCC version 4.8.3 and later. Unfortunately, I'm not supposed to upgrade the GCC because of various other dependencies.

I have already tried the --enable-new-dtags linker option, which effects in ignoring the rpath and takes first precedence of LD_LIBRARY_PATH followed by RUN_PATH.
Now, because this executable is tightly coupled with multiple customized libraries present at different location and used by the wide number of audience, I don't want to leave this first priority upto LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, which would be eventually set by the end user of this executable.
Is there any other option to ignore this default path added by linker and give precedence to rpath provided as linker options?

Build line: pkgs/gcc/4.8.0/bin/g++ main.cpp -Wl,-Bdynamic pkgs/gcc/6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -Wl,-rpath,'pkgs/gcc/6.3.0/lib64/

> readelf -d a.out | grep RPATH
>   0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/pkgs/gcc/4.8.0/lib64:/pkgs/gcc/6.3.0/lib64/]

Comment: Maybe you could compile with `-nodefaultlibs` and then you specify yourself needed rpath and gcc libraries to link to.

Comment: An other option could be to compile with `gcc -o` so that gcc only compiles and the invoke yourself the linker `ld file.o ....`.

Comment: @Oliv Linking it separately also doesn't work as the linker is the one implicitly placing a default rpath.